# Set ng-checked based on an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `select` dropdown. Upon selecting each value in dropdown, checkboxes are created using `ng-repeat`. All the values in the dropdown are supposed to be selected and corresponding checkboxes must be checked and stored in an array.

Whenever a checkbox changes I add it or remove it from array. When I change the dropdown, the checkboxes checked for previous dropdowns are gone.

How do I keep them checked based on the array that stores the checked values.

```
<div ng-repeat="flat in flatsArray" class="row" style="width:90%;">
       <div class="col-md-2">
          <input 
               type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{flat.flat_id}}"
               ng-false-value="'-1'" 
               //tried this but selctedFlats is an object
               ng-checked="userEventData.selectedFlats.indexOf(sFlats[$index])"  `userEventData.selectedFlats` is an object
              ng-change="checkChanged(sFlats[$index], flat)" 
              ng-model="sFlats[$index]" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-10"><label for="{{flat.flat_no}}">{{flat.flat_no}}</label></div>
    </div>
```

`$scope.userEventData.selectedFlats` is the array of checked values.

I could have done `ng-checked="userEventData.selectedFlats.indexOf(sFlats[$index])"` but `selectedFlats` contains object. I want to check with a value in the object

Comment: what is the definition of selected Flats?  Is it an object, and not an array?

Comment: @Fallenreaper it's an array of objects.

Comment: Well indexOf returns an INDEX, int, >= -1, So you would want to maybe change your expression slightly?  It doesnt want an object, it wants a boolean.  I feel this is harder than it should be.  Why not define a checked property within the flatsArray Object and just say:  `ng-checked="flat.checked"` It would create less Iteration, and cleaner code

Comment: @Fallenreaper hmm, ok. Write as answer and I will accept

Comment: Why are you using `ng-checked` with `ng-model` when the documentation tells you not to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NG-CHECKED is looking for an expression returning a state.  indexOf will return a numeric value >= -1.  Though this can be done will create a lot more processing because it will be running the functions over and over again to look for changes.

I would recommend something akin to: when you get your flats data, give the checked property there and assign it to what it needs to be.  It would create cleaner code, and you have 1 object to manipulate.  You can always parse it as needed.

```
ng-checked="flat.checked"
```

looks far cleaner, and creates less processing through looping arrays CONTINUALLY looking for changes.

Comment: hey i am trying what you said.. when I change the dropdown values, for some reason the `ng-change` on some selected checkboxes are not called. Can you think of a reason?

Comment: here's the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921448/ng-change-not-getting-called-on-checkbox